# Change List of Figures to Section instead Chapter in report/book class

Tags: table-of-contents

I am currently writing my thesis using the default report class.
By default this means that the lof and lot are included as seperate chapters.
However, I would like to include them as sections under a "Listings" chapter.
Is there any way to do this?

So far, I could only find a method using the "memoir" class.
Ideally I would not like to change the documentclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use package `tocbasic`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\addtotoclist[float]{lof}
\renewcommand*\listoffigures{\listoftoc[{\listfigurename}]{lof}}
\addtotoclist[float]{lot}
\renewcommand*\listoftables{\listoftoc[{\listtablename}]{lot}}

\setuptoc{lof}{leveldown}
\setuptoc{lot}{leveldown}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Listings}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \rule{5cm}{1cm}
  \caption{A Figure}%
\end{figure}
\lipsum[6-10]
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \rule{5cm}{1cm}
  \caption{A Table}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If all lists of owner `float` should be sections, then you could replace

```
\setuptoc{lof}{leveldown}
\setuptoc{lot}{leveldown}
```

by

```
\makeatletter
\doforeachtocfile[float]{\setuptoc{\@currext}{leveldown}}
\makeatother
```

If there should be a TOC entry for the lists, add feature `totoc` and if the lists should be numbered (with a TOC entry) add feature `numbered`:

```
\makeatletter
\doforeachtocfile[float]
  {\setuptoc{\@currext}{
    leveldown,%
    %totoc,%
    %numbered
  }}
\makeatother
```